# Is "whosoever" used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence, pronouns

Is "whosoever" used correctly in the following sentence? Is this sentence correct as a whole?

> **Whosoever** monk or priest sees this, may s/he take it, I've offered.

The context is: A man, in order to offer some money to the priest, goes to the temple but he sees no one there. So he puts the money there and utters the sentence mentioned above.

Comment: Did you try to look up ***whosoever*** in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Puctuation is a wonderful thing when used correctly.

> Whosoever, monk or priest, sees this, may they take it.  I have offered.

I've added parenthetical commas.  They mean the same as this:

> Whosoever (monk or priest) sees this, may they take it.  I have offered.

Parenthetical commas whisper little interruptions that should leave behind a grammatically correct and meaningful sentence if completely removed.

's/he' means the same as the singular 'they' but 's/he' is far more difficult to pronounce.  Odd to see in a quote.

"I have offered" sounds odd since it's typically a preposition but might simply be way to announce the offering.  If we don't take it as a preposition, it's a full blown sentence on it's own.

"I've offered" is informal and seems out of place next to the rest of this formal speech.

With these changes "Whosoever" is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

"Whosoever" is identical in meaning and function as "whoever." It doesn't make sense to say:

> Whoever monk or priest...

I would use different diction.

As for the sentence as a whole, you have a comma splice concerning the last clause. There should be a semi-colon after "it" instead of a comma.